# ChartJs: Changes in dataset.fill field between Chart.js v2 and v3

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to update an angular + knockout project to use ChartJS 3.7.1 instead of 2.7.2. My charts consist of several lines and areas. I am trying to fill an area of chart to show a threshold.

The code works perfectly in Chartjs V2:

[image]

but after updating to V3 the gray area is not shown anymore:

[image]

I tried and copied my configurations and data into a sample pages in Charjs official documentation website and I got the same result. There I found this table describing what is the situation with all the datasets and their ´fill´ argument and the ´Target´:

[image]

My configuration:

```json
"options": {
        "responsive": true,
        "maintainAspectRatio": false,
        "plugins": {
          "title": {
            "display": true,
            "text": "Taylor TL(vc)"
          },
          "legend": {
            "display": true,
            "position": "bottom",
            "labels": {}
          },
          "tooltips": {
            "mode": "nearest",
            "intersect": true,
            "callbacks": {}
          },
          filler: {
              propagate: true
          }
        },
        "animation": {
          "duration": 0
        },
        "scales": {
          "xAxis": {
            "display": true,
            "title": {
              "display": true,
              "text": "Cutting speed (m/min)",
              "font": {
                "size": 14
              }
            },
            "grid": {
              "display": false
            },
            "type": "logarithmic",
            "min": 196.290296651142,
            "max": 574.377427855796,
            "ticks": {
              "font": {
                "size": 11
              }
            }
          },
          "y_left": {
            "type": "logarithmic",
            "id": "y_left",
            "display": true,
            "title": {
              "display": true,
              "text": "Estimated tool life (min)",
              "font": {
                "size": 14
              }
            },
            "grid": {
              "display": false
            },
            "position": "left",
            "min": 1,
            "max": 91.5862261413244,
            "ticks": {
              "font": {
                "size": 11
              }
            }
          },
          "y_right": {
            "type": "linear",
            "id": "y_right",
            "display": false,
            "title": {
              "display": true,
              "text": "",
              "font": {
                "size": 14
              }
            },
            "grid": {
              "display": false
            },
            "position": "right",
            "min": 0,
            "max": 1,
            "ticks": {
              "font": {
                "size": 11
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

My simplified dataset:

```json
[
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "",
            "label": "D0",
            "borderWidth": 4,
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 4,
            "pointHoverRadius": 4,
            "showLine": false,
            "type": "scatter",
            "borderColor": "rgb(0,100,170)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(0,100,170)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 370,
                "y": 14.7610711521017
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "",
            "label": "D1",
            "borderWidth": 3,
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 3,
            "pointHoverRadius": 3,
            "showLine": false,
            "type": "scatter",
            "borderColor": "rgb(0,100,170)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(0,100,170)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 370,
                "y": 14.7610711521017
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "",
            "label": "D2",
            "borderWidth": 0.5,
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 0,
            "showLine": true,
            "type": "line",
            "borderDash": [
              10,
              4,
              2,
              4
            ],
            "borderColor": "rgb(0,100,170)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(0,100,170)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 370,
                "y": 1
              },
              {
                "x": 370,
                "y": 14.7610711521017
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "",
            "label": "D3",
            "borderWidth": 0.5,
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 0,
            "showLine": true,
            "type": "line",
            "borderDash": [
              10,
              4,
              2,
              4
            ],
            "borderColor": "rgb(0,100,170)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(0,100,170)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 196.290296651142,
                "y": 14.7610711521017
              },
              {
                "x": 370,
                "y": 14.7610711521017
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "",
            "label": "D4",
            "borderWidth": 0.5,
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 0,
            "showLine": true,
            "type": "line",
            "borderDash": [
              10,
              4,
              2,
              4
            ],
            "borderColor": "rgb(0,100,170)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(0,100,170)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 370,
                "y": 1
              },
              {
                "x": 370,
                "y": 14.7610711521017
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "",
            "label": "D5",
            "borderWidth": 0.5,
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 0,
            "showLine": true,
            "type": "line",
            "borderDash": [
              10,
              10
            ],
            "borderColor": "rgb(255,0,0)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(255,0,0)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 196.290296651142,
                "y": 60.7410041596544
              },
              {
                "x": 245.362870813927,
                "y": 60.7410041596544
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "",
            "label": "D6",
            "borderWidth": 0.5,
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 0,
            "showLine": true,
            "type": "line",
            "borderDash": [
              10,
              10
            ],
            "borderColor": "rgb(255,0,0)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(255,0,0)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 196.290296651142,
                "y": 7
              },
              {
                "x": 459.501942284637,
                "y": 7
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "",
            "label": "D7",
            "borderWidth": 0.5,
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 0,
            "showLine": true,
            "type": "line",
            "borderDash": [
              10,
              10
            ],
            "borderColor": "rgb(255,0,0)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(255,0,0)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 459.501942284637,
                "y": 1
              },
              {
                "x": 459.501942284637,
                "y": 7
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "",
            "label": "D8",
            "borderWidth": 0.5,
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 0,
            "showLine": true,
            "type": "line",
            "borderDash": [
              10,
              10
            ],
            "borderColor": "rgb(255,0,0)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(255,0,0)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 245.362870813927,
                "y": 1
              },
              {
                "x": 245.362870813927,
                "y": 60.7410041596544
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "",
            "label": "D9",
            "borderWidth": 2,
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 0,
            "showLine": true,
            "type": "line",
            "borderColor": "rgb(0,100,170)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(0,100,170)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 245.362870813927,
                "y": 60.7410041596544
              },
              {
                "x": 459.501942284637,
                "y": 7
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "",
            "label": "D10",
            "borderWidth": 2,
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 0,
            "showLine": true,
            "type": "line",
            "borderDash": [
              2,
              4
            ],
            "borderColor": "rgb(255,217,102)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(255,217,102)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 196.290296651142,
                "y": 15
              },
              {
                "x": 368.278921282049,
                "y": 15
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "",
            "label": "D11",
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 0,
            "showLine": true,
            "type": "line",
            "borderColor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgba(215,215,215,1)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 815.958124784052,
                "y": 91.5862261413244
              },
              {
                "x": 1028.44914644056,
                "y": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "-1",
            "label": "D12",
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 0,
            "showLine": true,
            "type": "line",
            "borderColor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgba(215,215,215,1)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 574.377427855796,
                "y": 91.5862261413244
              },
              {
                "x": 574.377427855796,
                "y": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "",
            "label": "D13",
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 0,
            "showLine": true,
            "type": "line",
            "borderColor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgba(215,215,215,1)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 84.3537803464742,
                "y": 91.5862261413244
              },
              {
                "x": 501.31702556873,
                "y": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "lineTension": 0,
            "fill": "-1",
            "label": "D14",
            "pointBorderWidth": 0,
            "pointRadius": 0,
            "pointHoverRadius": 0,
            "showLine": true,
            "type": "line",
            "borderColor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgba(215,215,215,1)",
            "yAxisID": "y_left",
            "data": [
              {
                "x": 196.290296651142,
                "y": 91.5862261413244
              },
              {
                "x": 196.290296651142,
                "y": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

As you can see, the ´fill´ field in all datasets are set to "" except for datasets 12 and 14, for which the ´fill´ is set to "-1". This is supposed to fill the area from ´origin´ to the line 11 and 13 respectively, but it does not work.

If I try and change the fill filed for the dataset 13, for example, from "" to true, then the area will be colored gray as it should be. but its a bit technically challenging to do it and I would prefer to figure out how to get it with ´fill´"-1"

Any idea how should I get this to work?

Comment: Apparently filling the are from a line to Y axis has been a feature in version below 3 and it disappeared in version 3 without any trace!!

To fix this a plugin can be used. Here is a link to another issue which is addressing this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74059346/how-to-fill-the-area-between-two-vertical-lines-in-the-chart-using-chartjs-libra